# D3 cartogram.js contiguous cartogram values not reflected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson, cartogram

I'm building a contiguous cartogram of inward refugee numbers, based on [this example](http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram/#deaths/2011) using cartogram.js for D3.

When I just use the refugee number, the map does not move.
[Base refugee number](http://www.thecourtofsybaris.net/map/base.html)

But when I add an arbitrary number to "r" on line, the it works. And the higher the arbitrary number, the more dramatic the change.
[Example 1](http://www.thecourtofsybaris.net/map/100.html)
[Example 2](http://www.thecourtofsybaris.net/map/500.html)

Why is this? Is it because some of my values are 0, or because the variance is too high?

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after starting this question, a friend and I found the answer. We suspect it was the zero values and the extreme variance of my dataset. Adding a scale seems to have sorted it. They are doing this in the example too, I just didn't notice.

```
// normalize the scale to positive numbers
    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([lo, hi])
        .range([1, 1000]);

// tell the cartogram to use the scaled values
    carto.value(function(d) {
        return scale(value(d));
    });
```